# Toolbaritem font color in Xamarin.Forms iOS app

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I am writing iOS app using Xamarin.Forms and I have an issue with my toolbar font color. I can't change it.

[image]

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItem>
<ToolbarItem Text="Menu2" Order="Secondary" />
<ToolbarItem Text="Menu1" Order="Secondary" />
```

How do I change the toolbar items font color to i.e. Red? I have tried with navigationpage custom renderer but with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Use code from this [link](https://github.com/daniel-luberda/XamarinFormsToolbarCustomFont/blob/master/iOS/CustomFontNavigationPageRenderer.cs)

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using ToolbarCustomFont.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using UIKit;

    [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof (NavigationPage), typeof (CustomFontNavigationPageRenderer))]
    namespace ToolbarCustomFont.iOS
    {
        // https://blog.xamarin.com/custom-fonts-in-ios/
        public class CustomFontNavigationPageRenderer : NavigationRenderer
        {
            public CustomFontNavigationPageRenderer()
            {
            }

            const string customFontName = "FontAwesome.ttf";
            nfloat customFontSize = 10;

            public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
            {
                base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

                if (this.NavigationBar == null) return;

                SetNavBarStyle();
    //          SetNavBarTitle();
                SetNavBarItems();
            }

            private void SetNavBarStyle()
            {
                NavigationBar.ShadowImage = new UIImage();
                NavigationBar.SetBackgroundImage(new UIImage(), UIBarMetrics.Default);
                UINavigationBar.Appearance.ShadowImage = new UIImage();
                UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetBackgroundImage(new UIImage(), UIBarMetrics.Default);
            }

            private void SetNavBarItems()
            {
                var navPage = this.Element as NavigationPage;

                if (navPage == null) return;

                var textAttributes = new UITextAttributes()
                {
                    Font = UIFont.FromName(customFontName, customFontSize)
                };

                var textAttributesHighlighted = new UITextAttributes()
                {
                    TextColor = Color.Black.ToUIColor(),
                    Font = UIFont.FromName(customFontName, customFontSize)
                };

                UIBarButtonItem.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes(textAttributes,
                    UIControlState.Normal);
                UIBarButtonItem.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes(textAttributesHighlighted,
                    UIControlState.Highlighted);
            }

        }
    }
```